# How to extract text from text nodes through Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I do have one HTML code from where I want to get text but almost texts are not within any HTML tags.

**Html**

```
<div class="div-estro">
    <b class="">Your</b> 
    <b class="">ID:</b>&nbsp;3915 
    <b class="">Time Limit:</b>&nbsp;00:19:56 
    <b class="">IP:</b>&nbsp;123.101.59.87 
    <b class="">Membership Period:</b>&nbsp;8 year <br>
    <b class="">CountryID:</b> 78 
    <b class="">Country:</b> US 
    <b class="">State:</b> OH 
    <b class="">City:</b> Akron 
    <b class="">Status:</b> Available 
    <b class="">Maximum Queue:</b> 4 
    <b class=""><br>CountryProxy:</b> 201.250.101.84:3372 
    <b class="">CountryIP:</b> 59.243.44.192 
</div>
```

I want to get the text from CountryIP and CountryProxy.

Expecting gettext string : **201.250.101.84:3372**

Expecting gettext string:**59.243.44.192**

I tried xpaths :

```
//div[@class='div-estro']//text()[12]

//div[@class='div-estro']//text()[13]
```

Above xpaths seems good when I evaluate using firebug. But when trying to get text using selenium, I am getting the exception.

Comment: what is the exception you get?

Comment: @rdmueller - It is  : `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: TypeError: Expected an element or WindowProxy, got: [object Text] {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the HTML you have shared it's a *text node* which contains the text **59.243.44.192** so to extract it you can use the following solution:

```
WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='div-estro']"));
String myCountryIP = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;", myElement).toString();
```

Update:

As per your comment update it's a text node which contains the text **201.250.101.84:3372** so to extract it you can use the following solution:

```
WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='div-estro']"));
String myCountryProxy = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].childNodes[24].textContent;", myElement).toString();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am facing some syntax error here , Can you please check this screenshot : https://prnt.sc/krmk24

Comment: @HelpingHands My bad, corrected it now. Please retest and let me know the status.

Comment: Also can you let me know what should I change in xpath to get this text : 201.250.101.84:3372

Comment: @HelpingHands Checkout my answer update and let me know the status

Comment: ok that seems fine . Can you just tell me how you decided 24 as child node?

Comment: Just count the _child nodes_, the desired _text_ is within a _text node_ at 24th position from top.

Comment: okay. Understood. Thanks again for all help. you saved my lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use XPath to get required text nodes as below:

```
String countryProxy = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.evaluate(\"//div[@class='div-estro']/b[.='CountryProxy:']/following-sibling::text()\", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext().textContent;").toString();
String countryIP = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.evaluate(\"//div[@class='div-estro']/b[.='CountryIP:']/following-sibling::text()\", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext().textContent;").toString();
```

Just update predicate for preceding `b` node to get required text:

```
b[.='State:']
b[.='Membership Period:']
...
```

Comment: Thanks Andersson for your help.